# How can I set an attribute on a functools.partialmethod?

Tags: python, django, functools

I have ported the following code from Django 2.2 to Django 3.1, and replaced `django.utils.functional.curry` with `functools.partialmethod`:

```
class CurrencyField(models.DecimalField):
    description = 'Currency amount'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_digits', 9)
        kwargs.setdefault('decimal_places', 2)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        if hasattr(cls, '_get_value_as_currency'):
            curried = partialmethod(cls._get_value_as_currency, field=self)
            curried.admin_order_field = self.name
            curried.short_description = self.verbose_name
            setattr(cls, f'get_{self.name}_as_currency', curried)
```

The method works correctly, however the `admin_order_field` and `short_description` attributes don't "stick" to the method like they did when I used `curry`.

```
getattr(cls, f'get_{self.name}_as_currency').short_description
*** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'short_description'
```

Is it possible to set attributes on a `partialmethod`, or will I need to replace this with some other mechanism?

Comment: Why not use FormField instead of ModelField? It is easy to register with admin.

Comment: This isn't for a form, it's for a model, with a convenience formatting method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a week or two of no answers, and a little more experimentation, I've given up on trying to get an attribute to stick to a `partialmethod` and instead dynamically defined a local function, and used the new `@admin.display` decorator from Django 3.2 to set the admin attributes, though the same could have been achieved without that syntactic sugar:

```
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        if hasattr(cls, '_get_value_as_currency'):
            @admin.display(
                ordering=self.name,
                description=self.verbose_name,
            )
            def getter(obj):
                return obj._get_value_as_currency(self)
            setattr(cls, f'get_{self.name}_as_currency', getter)
```